# Using variables from another function in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to search this but I don't quite understand. I am coming across this error so I formed a quick easy example.

```
def test():
    global a
    a = 0
    a+=1

def test2():
    a+=1
    print (a)


inp = input('a?')
if inp == 'a':
    test()
    test2()
```

When I input `a`. I expected the code to output 2. However, I get this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. When I searched around about this, I found that you need to use `global`, but I already am using it.

So I don't understand. Can someone briefly explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You need `global a` in `test2` as well.

Comment: What's the point of the `input` and `if`? How does it relate to the question?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, that works. Do you mind explaining why? I thought using `global a` in `test` allows you to use the variable anywhere within your code?

Comment: Even better: try to avoid using `global` names, they break the modularity of the code.

Comment: No, it just says that within that function, `a` should refer to the global variable.

Comment: @Barmar The `input` and `if` was just for a quick example to try demonstrate what I was having a problem with. Sorry if it was not the best example.

Comment: Couldn't you demonstrate it by just writing `test()` and `test2()` without the `if`?

Comment: Okay I understand now, sorry I'm just a bit new to this. Thanks again for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `global` declaration only applies within that function. So the declaration in `test()` means that uses of the variable `a` in that function will refer to the global variable. It doesn't have any effect on other functions, so if `test2` also wants to access the global variable, you need the same declaration there as well.

```
def test2():
    global a
    a += 1
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can return the modified value like:

```
def test():
    a = 0
    a+=1
    return a

def test2(a):
    a+=1
    print (a)


inp = input('a?')
if inp == 'a':
    a = test()
    test2(a)
```

2) Or you can use a class:

```
class TestClass:

    a = 0

    def test(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.a+=1

    def test2(self):
        self.a+=1
        print (self.a)
```

Usage of option 2:

```
>>> example = TestClass()
>>> example.test()
>>> example.test2()
2
```

Comment: I think if you'd also explained why the original code didn't work then this would have been the better answer (not using `global` is almost always preferable) but it doesn't address what's actually not working in the original code.